# Enumitem: parent list change the properties of nested lists

Tags: enumitem

If I have a nested list (enumitem-based) like:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item A
\item A
\item
  \begin{enumerate}[nosep,leftmargin=3cm,labelsep=0pt]
  \item B
  \item K
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Z
    \item P
    \end{itemize}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{itemize}
```

the nested list will take the value of the parent, giving weird results like:

[image]

(see how Z/P are close to the label)

Is it possible to "isolate" the setting to a single list? I guess I could manually write all parameters, in the definition of `itemize`, but I don't know what are the default values, nor what is the list of all values to set (and it seems a bit dirty).

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcommand*{\marvosymbol}[1]{{\fontfamily{mvs}\fontencoding{U}\fontseries{m}\fontshape{n}\selectfont\char#1}}
\setlist[itemize]{label={\strut\textcolor{blue!50!white}{\marvosymbol{123}}},leftmargin=6mm,}


\begin{document}


\begin{itemize}
\item A
\item A
\item
  \begin{enumerate}[nosep,leftmargin=3cm,labelsep=0pt]
  \item B
  \item K
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Z
    \item P
    \end{itemize}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What's the desired output here? Which settings do or don't you want to be inherited? Presumably, you don't want the next level to forget the increased margin?

Comment: @cfr everything that make sense I guess ^^ Here I would like more space between the label and the text for the last itemize, maybe a bit more space between items (not so sure if they differ here, but it is possible since nosep remove separation of items) etc… More precisely, of course nested items should be "indented", so the last list should start more on the right than the first list. Otherwise, all other settings should NOT be inherited, basically I do.

Comment: hm, try to remove local option for `enumerate`. After than your list get usual, nice format. What you now get with your code is expected result.

Comment: @Zarko well, my whole point is that I do want the `enumerate` to have some local options…

Comment: But not on this way. Followed `itemize` is nested in it, so it should consider "starting point". If you like that not, than you need to close `enumerate` first or to `itemize` add local definition of its features.

Comment: As @Zarko says, this is kind of how it works. Especially see the discussion of `labelsep` in `enumitem`'s documentation, where the lack of any default and a suggested solution is discussed. Basically, the recommendation is to set an explicit value as default so you can keep control of it, since LaTeX otherwise just uses whatever it happens to be at the time.

Comment: I'm fine with setting a default value. Just, I don't know the list of all default values I need to set (e.g. nosep will change multiple variables), and what is there typical value (I guess LaTeX chooses some glue with some allowed stretching to have a pleasant look). I was hoping to find a key 'reset all variables" but I can't find any ^^'

Comment: Note that most list parameters have levels, such as `\leftmargini` , but there is only one `\labelsep`.

Comment: Add `\edef\defaultlabelsep{\the\labelsep}` before changing it, if you want to change it back.

Comment: @JohnKormylo ah very interesting, so labelsep is kind of tge only one I need to restore? Apparently it often defaults to 0.5em (github issue)

Comment: Actually, the defaults are all set by the document class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want something like this? Or, rather, given that what you want is not available, is something like this a reasonable workaround?

Basically, we save the values of the various dimensions at the start of the document and set all lists to use those values. A macro is also provided for printing the current and default values.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/700973/ addaswyd o gwestiwn tobiasBora: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/700886/
\usepackage[scale=.75]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newcommand*{\marvosymbol}[1]{{\fontfamily{mvs}\fontencoding{U}\fontseries{m}\fontshape{n}\selectfont\char#1}}
\setlist[itemize]{label={\strut\textcolor{blue!50!white}{\marvosymbol{123}}},leftmargin=6mm,}
\newlength\defaultlabelsep
\newlength\defaultitemsep
\newlength\defaultparsep
\newlength\defaulttopsep
\newlength\defaultpartopsep
\newlength\defaultlistparindent
\newlength\defaultlabelwidth
\newlength\defaultitemindent
\newlength\defaultleftmargin
\newlength\defaultrightmargin
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \setlength\defaultlabelsep{\labelsep}%
  \setlength\defaultitemsep{\itemsep}%
  \setlength\defaultparsep{\parsep}%
  \setlength\defaulttopsep{\topsep}%
  \setlength\defaultpartopsep{\partopsep}%
  \setlength\defaultlistparindent{\listparindent}%
  \setlength\defaultlabelwidth{\labelwidth}%
  \setlength\defaultitemindent{\itemindent}%
  \setlength\defaultleftmargin{\leftmargin}%
  \setlength\defaultrightmargin{\rightmargin}%
  \setlist{%
    labelsep=\defaultlabelsep,
    itemsep=\defaultitemsep,
    parsep=\defaultparsep,
    topsep=\defaulttopsep,
    partopsep=\defaultpartopsep,
    listparindent=\defaultlistparindent,
    labelwidth=\defaultlabelwidth,
    itemindent=\defaultitemindent,
    leftmargin=\defaultleftmargin,
    rightmargin=\defaultrightmargin,
  }%
  \showlstvalues
}
\NewDocumentCommand \showlstvalues {}
{%
  labelsep=\the\labelsep;\par
  itemsep=\the\itemsep;\par
  parsep=\the\parsep;\par
  topsep=\the\topsep;\par
  partopsep=\the\partopsep;\par
  listparindent=\the\listparindent;\par
  labelwidth=\the\labelwidth;\par
  itemindent=\the\itemindent;\par
  leftmargin=\the\leftmargin;\par
  rightmargin=\the\rightmargin;\par
  defaultlabelsep=\the\defaultlabelsep;\par
  defaultitemsep=\the\defaultitemsep;\par
  defaultparsep=\the\defaultparsep;\par
  defaulttopsep=\the\defaulttopsep;\par
  defaultpartopsep=\the\defaultpartopsep;\par
  defaultlistparindent=\the\defaultlistparindent;\par
  defaultlabelwidth=\the\defaultlabelwidth;\par
  defaultitemindent=\the\defaultitemindent;\par
  defaultleftmargin=\the\defaultleftmargin;\par
  defaultrightmargin=\the\defaultrightmargin;\par
}
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
  \item A
  \item A
  \item
  \begin{enumerate}[nosep,leftmargin=3cm,labelsep=0pt]
    \item B
    \item K
    \begin{itemize}
      \item Z
      \item P
    \end{itemize}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{itemize}\begin{itemize}
  \item \showlstvalues
  \item
  \begin{enumerate}[nosep,leftmargin=3cm,labelsep=0pt]
    \item \showlstvalues
    \begin{itemize}
      \item \showlstvalues
    \end{itemize}
  \end{enumerate}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image: lists with and without default settings and non-lists of default and current values]